# What is the power of a Turing-machine that cannot write?

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines

What is the power of a Turing-machine that cannot write?

So it can still read and go back and forth on the tape, but it cannot write.

I am wondering what this would be equivalent to in the computational hierarchy.

I suppose this would be a finite-state automaton, but it can go left *and* right along the input: does that increase its powers?

Comment: It's called a two-way finite automaton.

Comment: @xavierm02 Ah, it has a name, great!  Is it more powerful than a one-way FSA?  I am guessing not but don't know ... that's really my question.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, it is equivalent to finite automaton (even if you allow non-determinism).

Comment: @xavierm02 Yes, just read that as well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-way_finite_automaton  Thanks!!